# Symfony 2 apc caching error

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine, apc

I am moving my Symfony 2 project to production environment on shared hosting. When I execute the file app.php I get error of

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in /data/web/virtuals/53627/virtual/www/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php on line 40
```

I contacted the hosting provider and was told that they no longer user APC caching, which seems to be outdated, so they moved further.

Is there any way how to omit APC caching using Symfony + Doctrine?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check out your `app/config.yml`: the Doctrine cache drivers are pretty configurable, and [as the doc states](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.rst#caching-drivers), you could just set them to `array`. That would look pretty much like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: array
        query_cache_driver: array
        result_cache_driver: array
```

Also note that this is basically the default configuration, so the defaults must've been overridden.

Comment: Thank you kix, even if I use this snippet I'm still getting the same error. I actually don't get why. Situation is the same even if use very default config.yml.

Comment: I just solved the situation by modifying app.php, line $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); TO $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);. I have no idea where there was false set as default. Leaving this comment if anyone bumped into same trouble.

Comment: Just do `php app/console console:clear --env=prod` if you are on production. btw changing to `array` most likely will have a negative effect on performance.

Comment: new AppKernel('prod', true) => means in prod with **debug**. I guess in debug you are not using the cache, that's why you don't have any problem anymore. Do you see apc when running phpinfo ? In phpinfo / "Additional .ini files parsed" section, the I have "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-apcu.ini"